# Why do we use the term "cepstral" in MFCCs, and how does it related to the cepstral domain?

Tags: speech-processing, mfcc, dct, cepstral-analysis

As I know, we can get the cepstrum by taking the Inverse Discrete Fourier Transform (IDFT) of the log of the power spectrum.

[image]

[image]

And we can get the Mel-frequency cepstral coefficients (MFCCs) by taking the Discrete Cosine Transform (DCT) of the log filterbank energies.

But I didn't understand the following two points:

- Why do we use the term "cepstral" in MFCCs when we use DCT instead of IDFT?
- How does MFCCs **relate to** the cepstral domain according to the reference [here](http://madelinebriere.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Independent_Study-1.pdf#subsubsection.3.4.6)?

Comment: Can you please have a look at [this](https://users.cs.northwestern.edu/~pardo/courses/eecs352/papers/TheCepstrum-AGuide.pdf) as cited in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cepstrum) and then perhaps amend the question with further points that may have remained unclear?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/15945/8202). DCT can be treated as an IDFT in this case.