# Understanding MFCC

Tags: speech-processing, speech-recognition, mfcc

I am not from electrical or electronic background so my knowledge will be lacking.

MFCC is represented by 39 values for each window frame. 12 values are the mel filter-bank and we get 13th value by taking DCT[ Is this right ]?
So rest are the delta and double delta and their energy.

Below is the equation for calculating mel frequency cepstrum:

[image]

It appears to me that it gives a single value for a window frame. I understand that S[m] is the log energies for each M filter. Does c[n] refers to coefficients of n the frame?

Isn't the equation 6.145 summing the log energies over M filters?. If there are 13 mel filters(M=13) then equation 6.145 appears to be the sum of 13 log energies which gives 1 value. Isn't this logic right.

I need to understand how 13 values are found from equation 6.145

Comment: Does [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/15945/8202) answer help?

Comment: not entirely. I have edited my question. Can you check ?

Comment: All 13 coefficients are from DCT. I can try to bake a full answer later. In your equation, $S[m]$ is the log-energy in $m$'th mel filter bank. Let's say in one frame of audio you have 13 log-energies. You get vector $S$ with 13 values. Now you fit $\cos$ functions. You can either fit 13 $\cos$ functions to get 100% accurate representation, giving you 13 MFCC's (DCT coefficients). Or you can take first 6 coefficients, ignoring the 6 highest. This will give you the overall shape of the spectrum without fine details (represented by higher coefficients).

Comment: I have updated the equation but i guess i got a bit idea about it. So c[n] are the different coefficients for a window frame? where n ranges from 0 to 12 ?

Comment: See that you get $c[n]$  where $n$ goes up to $M-1$. $n$ is also inside the cosine function. As you take higher coefficients ($c[6]$, etc.) the cosine function has higher frequency.

Comment: Yes, precisely!

Comment: Yes. I missed that. Thanks for being patient.