# What are the differences between fft and dct?

Tags: image-processing

what are the differences  between Fourier transform and cosine transform..... 
i try to find the typical answer 
the difference ,from where ,the size of input and output form,in time complexity,the domain ,the effect on image itself .

Comment: You could have asked for the difference between the standard "discrete Fourier transform" (DFT) and "discrete cosine transforms" (DCTs) (because there are several breeds). The FFT is only one common fast implementation. I would suggest you to have a look at a previous answer 
[What is the difference between a Fourier transform and a cosine transform?](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/13/what-is-the-difference-between-a-fourier-transform-and-a-cosine-transform) before making your question more specific.

Comment: ya know guys, i've seen this point made now about a half dozen times just in the past week.  let's give the guy a break.  FFT is a fast way of doing a DFT.  fine.  but we know every time someone refers to the mapping as an *"FFT"*, we know he/she means DFT.  and if it bothers you enough, edit the damn question.  including the title.

Answer (score 3):

First, you should compare the DCT to the DFT, not the FFT. FFT is just a family of algorithms to approximate the DFT.

Also:

> [...] 
>   In particular, a DCT is a Fourier-related transform similar to the discrete Fourier transform (DFT), **but using only real numbers.** DCTs are **equivalent to DFTs of roughly twice the length**, operating on real data with even symmetry (since the Fourier transform of a real and even function is real and even), where in some variants the input and/or output data are shifted by half a sample. There are eight standard DCT variants, of which four are common.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform